# How to connect with two networks but use one to connect with a single address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have two networks. One is Ethernet, second is WLAN. I can't connect to some address using Ethernet. A destination is reachable using WLAN. I can't use only WLAN because it's quite constrained.

Is it possible to configure Windows 10 to connect with a single address using WLAN but use Ethernet by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom routes using the following command:

```
route ADD <Destination-IP> MASK <subnet mask of destination> <Gateway-IP>
```

So for example you are trying to reach "192.168.100.10" and the default gateway of your wifi is "192.168.178.1" then the command would be:

```
route ADD 192.168.100.10 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.178.1
```

(255.255.255.255 only if the target is a single ip, if its a network you will have to enter the appropriate subnet mask)

If you want the route to persist through restarts add '-p' after route like so:

```
route -p ADD ...
```

Comment: Man! You're my personal Jesus. You saved me a lot of effort. Thank you so much!